# Unable to save my temporary layer

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3, export, qgsvectorlayer

I am getting the following error while saving my temporary layer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(): argument 4 has unexpected type 'str'
```

This is the script I am using:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsVectorLayer
import os
layer = iface.activeLayer() # layer which has a selection 
feat = layer.selectedFeatures()
fields = layer.fields()
crs = layer.crs().authid()
selection = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=' + crs, 'temp', 'memory')
dp = selection.dataProvider()
dp.addAttributes(fields)
selection.updateFields()
feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feat in feats:
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    feature.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
    dp.addFeatures([feature])
    dp.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(selection)
print(selection)
dg = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(selection, r"D:\Destn.shp",QgsCoordinateTransformContext(),"ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use like this:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(#layer#, #file_path#, #transform_context#, #options#)
```

```
file_path= "/Path/To/File.shp"    
transform_context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext() 
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(selection,
                                          file_path, 
                                          transform_context,
                                          options
                                          )
```

---

You can also use `writeAsVectorFormat`:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(#layer#, #file path#, #encoding#, #crs#, #driver name#)
```

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(selection,       # layer
                                        r"D:\Destn.shp", # file path
                                        "UTF-8",         # encoding
                                        selection.crs(), # crs
                                        "ESRI Shapefile" # driver name
                                       )
```